# SQL Server - How to create IF EXISTS...SELECT AND SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dml

I am attempting to create an `IF/ELSE` check on my code in order to ensure that the parameters `@BookTitle` and `@GenreName` are records within the the tables `BookGenre` and Genre before attempting to delete them. I attempted to write this line of code, but received an error,

> An expression of type non-Boolean type specified where condition is expected.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Library.Book WHERE Title = @BookTitle AND 
               SELECT Id FROM Library.Genre WHERE Name = @GenreName)
ELSE
```

I need some direction on how to create an `IF EXISTS` statement expression that includes two separate select statements as part of the IF check.

Here is the entire Store Procedure below (Without the IF statement):

```
PROCEDURE [Library].[DeleteDateFromBookGenre]
        -- Parameters to select which record delete
        @BookTitle nvarchar(200),
        @GenreName nvarchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Library.Book WHERE Title = @BookTitle) 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Library.Book WHERE Title = @BookTitle)

        -- Deletes the specified and selected data from the Genre and Book table.
        DELETE FROM Library.BookGenre 
        WHERE BookId IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM Library.Book
        WHERE Title = @BookTitle
        ) AND
        GenreId IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM Library.Genre
        WHERE Name = @GenreName
        )
    END
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you are trying to perform the check since you don't do anything exciting, e.g. `throw` an exception, if the rows aren't found.. If you simply go ahead and execute the `delete` statement then you can check [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If it is `0` then no rows were deleted indicating either the title, genre or both were not found. If it's `1` then the book/genre pair was unique. If `> 1` you may be surprised.

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear. I wanted to purely know more about IF statements and was attempting to test it on this procedure, even though I don't do anything "exciting" in it. I couldn't find the answer I was looking for, but was able to get my answer down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses are off; you need two `EXISTS` conditions:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Library.Book WHERE Title = @BookTitle
          ) AND 
   EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Library.Genre WHERE Name = @GenreName
          )
BEGIN
    . . .
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was exactly was I was looking for.